# Someone can check my session?

Tags: php, mysql, session

Please someone can check whether my session is working or not. 
I am not sure as i am still beginner.

login.php is the main page for user to login the username and password :

```
    <body>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="imgcontainer">
            <img src="KBR2xN6.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            </div>

            <div class="container">
            <label><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="name" required>
            <br />

            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pass" required>

            <button type="submit">Login</button>
            <button type="reset" class="cancelbtn">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </body>
```

As for connections.php is to connect to the local server :

```
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "netbook 1 malaysia";

try {
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo 'Connection Failed : '.$ex->getMessage();
}
```

As for session.php i am not sure:

```
session_start();
include('connections.php');

$username = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM pengguna WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
$result = $connect->query($sql);

if($result->rowcount()>0){
    foreach($result AS $data){
        $_SESSION['name'] = $data['name'];
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $data['pass'];

    echo "<script>alert('Login Success');
            window.location.href='view.php';
            </script>";
    }
}

else {
    echo "<script>alert('Login Failed');
            window.location.href='login.php';
            </script>"; 
}
```

Check for me please.

Comment: go to your view.php and do a `print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: The form posts back to itself `action=""` not to `action="session.php"`

Comment: Form action ='' so login.php will post to itself(login.php).you should change to action="session.php"

Comment: thanks, i did that. but how do i know my session working ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code to your view.php file.

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

If it prints values you saved in session then its working.

Comment: No his problem is about the action='' in his form

Comment: Hello maverick, i do as u say but it print this :
Array ( [name] => [pass] => )

Comment: @Dikwan, means session is not working..Did you set session before printing session ? Are you sure you are getting data in $result variable ? pls check it first..